# How to build your own java source files into the SDK, using Linux

Tags: android, linux, sdk

I'm able to create a jar file with my own class(es), using the ADT (20.0.3) in Eclipse Juno on Windows 7.  This is accomplished by selecting the "Is Library" check box in the Properties -> Android window, when pressing Alt + Enter on the project selected in Eclipse.  This "automagically" generate a .jar file).

I can also add my created jar file to a local test server and then include the location in the Android SDK Manager (20.0.3) -> Tools -> Manage Add-on Sites -> User Defined Sites, to get my .jar file listed and installed, using the Packages overview of the Android SDK manager.

I'm also able to use the extra added .jar file, when building an application.

So far, so good.  All works fine.

However, this is all on ***Windows 7***.

What I would like to know, is how to do this using the build mechanism of the SDK on ***Linux***.

I would like to add the Java source files inside a subdirectory of "vendor".

So, what steps have to be taken to:

- add my files to the SDK build mechanism
- let the SDK build mechanism build my .jar file (taking along my java files) during the SDK build process (just like the ADT does on Windows, using the "Is library" option)
- know where the output will be stored

I can find a lot of solutions for Windows builds, but this I already know (see above).  However, I can't find information on how to do this while building the SDK on Linux.

Hope someone can shed a light on this.

Best rgds,
--Geert

Comment: Found out that it's just a matter of having an Android.mk file with the correct content, to finally end up with the wanted Java files to be compiled into a jar file.
By the way: wondering why this thread has -2.  Would like to know what I did wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Only way you can find out is by actually following the same steps on Linux as you did for Windows. Eclipse works the same for Windows/Mac/Linux as it runs on top of JVM. So there is not much OS specificity that i see.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I want to automate this process on Linux, while building the SDK from the command line.  There's no Eclipse involved in the automation.